# "10.9.8.5", port 5433 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?

Tags: python, postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to tunnel to my database using python, but crashes with a warning:

```
"10.9.8.5", port 5433 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

My python settings:

`

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ('10.132.230.2', 22),
            ssh_username="<usrnm>",
            ssh_password="<psswrd>", 
            remote_bind_address=('10.9.8.5', 5433)) as server:
         
            server.start()
            print ("server connected")
            params = {
                'database': "<dbnm>",
                'user':  "postgres",
                'password':  "<dbpsswrd>",
                'host': '10.9.8.5',
                'port': 5433
                }
            conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
            curs = conn.cursor()
```

Everything below happened in 10.9.8.5
I tried to edit postgres configs:

1. i have changed postgresql.conf[image: postgresql.conf]
2. i have changed pg_hba.conf(i added the last row)[image: pg_hba.conf]
3. i restarted postgres

but it didn't help

ok, after searching for more, I came across the fact that there may be a problem in the firewall
i allowed port 5433[image]

then i restarted server but i still get this message

Comment: Please edit the question with details about your network setup: what machines do these IP addresses refer to, and how are they connected?

Comment: @Thomas Of course, I'm not a sysadmin and we don't have one now (otherwise I wouldn't have to deal with this), but I'll try to answer as I know:
there is a cluster that consists of 6 nodes, 10.132.230.2 is the main ip to which they connect via ssh, so that they can then connect to the nodes via ssh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're telling your database client to connect directly to 10.9.8.5:5433. That's not how tunneling works.

The `SSHTunnelForwarder` opens a port on your *local* machine, which it then forwards to the given `remote_bind_address` through the intermediate ssh server. It doesn't let you magically access the remote server under its original IP address. So you need to use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` when connecting to the database server, and use the right port number.

By default, `SSHTunnelForwarder` chooses a random available port on the local host; the chosen port number is revealed afterwards through the `local_bind_port` property. However, by default it opens this port to other hosts as well (0.0.0.0). This is not needed, so it's better to be explicit and bind only to localhost a.k.a. `127.0.0.1`; you can do this with [the `local_bind_address` argument](https://sshtunnel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder).

Putting all of that together:

```
with SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ('10.132.230.2', 22),
            ssh_username="<usrnm>",
            ssh_password="<psswrd>", 
            remote_bind_address=('10.9.8.5', 5433),
            local_bind_address=('127.0.0.1',)) as server: # Open port on localhost
         
            server.start()
            print ("server connected")
            params = {
                'database': "<dbnm>",
                'user':  "postgres",
                'password':  "<dbpsswrd>",
                'host': '127.0.0.1',            # Connect to localhost...
                'port': server.local_bind_port, # ... on the chosen port
                }
            conn = psycopg2.connect(**params)
            curs = conn.cursor()
```